What does "dare not" mean in a literary context?
Usually, when I hear the word "dare," it is used in sentences like "How dare you," "Don't you dare," "I dare you to do something," and so on.
This is why I find it baffling to see "dare" used in the following contexts.

In The X-Men (Uncanny X-Men) issue #1 (September 1963), Professor X puts Angel, Beast, Cyclops, and Iceman through training exercises one at a time. When it is Angel's turn, Professor X has this to say.


Professor X: All right, Angel…it's your turn! Are you receiving my thought clearly? Good! Now, be sharp…today we test your wing reflex! You dare not make a mistake!

In the book Star Wars: Red Harvest, Darth Scabrous has captured Padawan Hestizo Trace and is planning to sacrifice her, with an altar, knife and everything. However, Trace manages to escape and disrupt the Sith Lord's plans. In response, Darth Scabrous says this.

Darth Scabrous: No! You shall not. You dare not!

I confess that I laughed so hard when I read that line, because my first thought was, "Dude, you were planning to cut out her heart and eat it. Why wouldn't she dare to avoid such a fate? Pfft. Typical Sith narcissism!"
Anyway, does anyone have a clue what "dare not" means in literary contexts such as the above?

There are two different issues here: an unusual form of negation, and the meaning(s) of dare.
Taking the negation first: “You dare not!” is essentially equivalent to “You do not dare!”, just more old-fashioned and literary.  The excellent answer by tchrist gives a more thorough comparison of these two forms of negation.
On the meaning of dare: Fundamentally, to dare to do X means to have the courage to do X. So a sentence like “Who dares to challenge me?” means “Who has the courage to challenge me?”  However, the bare positive form — something like I dare to go alone — is very rarely used, and very old-fashioned/literary indeed.  In ordinary usage today, dare mostly appears in negated, questioning, and conditional forms — “When mum looks like that, I don’t dare say no!”, “What startup would dare to challenge Microsoft?” — plus a few set phrases, like your examples “How dare you…” and “Don’t you dare!”
Your other example, “I dare you to do something”, is slightly different: it’s a derived usage, meaning “to challenge someone to do something”. Presumably it arose originally from challenges phrased like “Do you dare go into the haunted house?” “You wouldn’t dare go in…”, getting abstracted first as a description of such challenges “John dared Tim to go in…”, and then getting used directly for the challenge itself “I dare you to go in there…”  (It would be good to back up my ‘presumably’ with citations from a serious source; I’m travelling now and don’t have access to a good historical dictionary.)
Going back to your original example, “You dare not!” means exactly what you thought: the powerful villain is saying their seemingly-helpless victim won’t have the courage to fight back. Which is not entirely narcissism: however terrible a fate is, fighting back can often take more courage than giving up, and intimidating a victim by telling them they should feel powerless to resist is a classic (and often effective) tactic of people in a position of power.

Any verb can be negated by placing the not after that verb. That used to be the only possible way to do it, but now we can use do support.
Sometimes.
We only do this with auxiliary verbs in Modern English, such as has not, is not, does not, do not plus of course all the modal verbs like should not, will not, may not as well as the semi-modals like dare not, need not, ought not.
For non-auxiliary verbs, these days you use the do auxiliary instead, but the not still follows the inflected verb and the old verb goes in the infinitive:.

He sleeps not. / He does not sleep.
She wants not. / She does not want.

You can do this with semi-modals, but you break their use as a uninflected modal and turn it into a regular verb to so.

He dare not ask you. / He does not dare to ask you.
She need not ask your permission. / She does not need to ask your permission.
You dare not try. / You do not dare  (to) try. / Don't you dare try.(?)

You can't do that with true modals because they have no infinitive form the way to need and to dare both possess.

I think what the OP is wondering about whether modal dare can really be used to convey deontic modality. I'm with OP in that I don't think it can.

@Araucaria-Him I’d considered observing that, for the most part, modals work poorly—if at all!—as classical second-person imperatives, particularly when you skip the subject the way you do with Get lost, Help me, Be good. Something like You SHALL behave! is clearly deontic, but it hasn’t the same syntax as a simple Behave! has. Yet imperatives like Dare anything, Dare nothing, Dare to dream ᴅᴏ have that syntax! I'm unsure those are ‘modal’ uses like I dare not take it is. I also see three modals in For a reward they ᴡɪʟʟ go in where you ᴅᴀʀᴇ ɴᴏᴛ not, or at any rate ᴄᴀɴɴᴏᴛ.

Both examples mean "Do not dare." The first example. based on context, is an encouragement in the form of a threat. The second is just a threat.

Why, it means the same thing as in "don't you dare"!
Wiktionary (and also the tags on this question) tells us that dare is a semimodal verb.

Dare is a semimodal verb. When used as an auxiliary, the speaker can choose whether to use do-support and the auxiliary "to" when forming negative and interrogative sentences. For example, "I don't dare (to) go", "I dare not go", "I didn't dare (to) go", and "I dared not go" are all correct.'

You're correct that it's Sith narcissism to threaten someone who is escaping such an already-threatening situation, as though after they wound your pride in such a way you will somehow make it worse for them...

Well, arguably "you dare not" is just declarative, while "don't you dare" is imperative. Scabrous is a titch incoherent, though, and maybe intends a bit of the imperative. The Sith are also given to overblown theatrics and sometimes-stiltedly lofty language, a la Dr Doom.
